# Keycloak with Spring boot with F5 on https not working

Tags: keycloak

We are using keycloak with Spring boot and configured F5 load balancer with Https. keycloak with Spring boot is on http, when we try to access keycloak from F5 with https url, login screen appears but after login it again stuck/looping at main page

tried setting keycloak.ssl-required=all or external, but still issue persist

Please help to resolve